# how to handle exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception

I'm using  asp.net mvc4

In  my  `Global.asax.cs` I  have

```
          void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //We clear the response
        Response.Clear();




        {

            Response.Redirect("~/Shared/_Error");
        }

        //We clear the error
        Server.ClearError();
    }
```

that  gives me a nice   error  message  for the user

but  for  me as a developper  i want  to  see  some informations  about   the  exception

how  can i handel  that ?  can i  use  a simple file  to  store  that informations?

Comment: `Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();`

Comment: Log information about the error.  The exception (including the message, stack trace, any inner exceptions, any additional data on custom exception classes, etc.), some runtime contextual information (values used to invoke the functionality for example), etc.  Any useful information.  You can log it to a file, sure.  Or a database.  Or an email message.  Or any number of places.  There are multiple logging frameworks from which to choose which can assist in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the last exception using:

```
Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();
```

`exc.ToString()` should give you all the information you need (and more).  You can log it, display it to the user, etc.

You might also look at bolt-on tools like [ELMAH](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/) that support email notifications, logging, etc.

More information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/24395wz3(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: ELMAH also supports a real-time URL for viewing the exception history.  Indispensable!